# I'm having difficulty getting rid of these "shadows" around my donut drips

Tags: rendering

here's the preview can anyone help at all? this is in the render mode and I thought it would be lightning but it wasn't
[image: donut render]

[[image: donut render 22]

Comment: It looks wrong face direction. Try to flip the normals on the ominous faces. You can easily find them by enabling backface culling (Switch to Solid view mode at the upper right corner of the 3d view, then open its option menu with the little arrow near the 3 spheres).  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/normals.html?highlight=normals

Comment: ..or turn on Face Orientation on the Viewport Overlay menu. If the faces are pointing in the wrong direction they'll display in red.